# Yii2 | Файловая структура поиска по сайту

Tags: yii2, search

Я столкнулся с проблемой, что как правильно построить файловую структуру поиска по сайту.

у меня есть контроллер `SiteController`, функция `actionNews`, которая выводит все новости.Также она принимает `Yii::$app->request->queryParams` и сортирует по дате.

функция `actionNews`

```
 $model = new News();
        $dataProvider = $model->getAllNews(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('news', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
```

сортировка

```
$query = $this::find()->where(['status' => $this::ACTIVE_NEWS]);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'sort' => [
                'defaultOrder' => [
                    'date' => SORT_DESC
                ]
            ],
        ]);

        if (!($this->load($params))) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        if (!empty($this->getAttribute('date'))) {
            $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->getAttribute('date')));
            $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'date', $date]);
        }

        return $dataProvider;
```

Поиск я подключаю в header проекта, чтобы был на всех страницах.

Стоит ли мне передавать параметр `search` сюда и просто дописать функционал по сортировке(условие если есть параметр search сделать поиск), или лучше создать новую модель, класс и работать с ним
Также в будущем хочу добавить elasticsearch.

Как лучше поступить, подскажите пожалуйста.
И как мне вечно передавать мою модель `$model = new News();` в мой `layout/main.php` для работы с `activeform`, потому что я просто сделал форму с помощью HTML и отправляю её на `actionNews`

подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сделать поиск по сайту.

Comment: Сделай для новостей отдельный контроллер.

Answer (score 2):

На вашем месте я бы сделал свой виджет и action к нему с поиском и заполнением модели и рендерил бы его где душе было угодно. А в нем создавалась бы модель и не нужно было бы ее прокидывать куда-то. Зачем признак $search? Просто делайте load() и если true, то идете искать, а если форма пустая, то либо показываете пустоту либо поиск по дефолтным параметрам.

Comment: то есть правильный вариант решения задачки создать свой виджет и его подключать где нужно? Тогда как мне быть с моей функцией actionNews, которая выводит все мои новости, или это всё уже будет в виджете? Я просто хочу найти правильное решения и делать по нему. но в интернете нету никаких ответов

Comment: и как после поиска, мне перенаправить пользователя на страницу news с уже отфильтрованными данными? Ведь он там у меня также принимает параметры поиска и т.д

Comment: или виджет просто будет выводить форму? А при поиске отправлять на actionNews и там уже фильтровать?

Comment: "Правильного решения" нет) Кто-то может предложить лучше и т.д.
Виджет рисует форму, в папку с виджетом добавьте например action, пусть он делает поиск. Потом в нужных контроллерах подключите этот action через метод "actions" и все. Я не вникаю в реализацю конкретно сейчас, но думаю вам стоит посмотреть в этом направлении.
Вот ссылка на создание виджетов:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/structure-widgets#creating-widgets

Comment: окей. Спасибо большое за помощь. Просто не хочется писать гавнокод, а хочется сделать правильную структуру и хороший код.

Comment: Не за что. Будут вопросы - пишите

Comment: У меня возник вопрос. Я все сделал, и суперово работате. Как можно в GET передавать параметр search или q, я не могу его передавать, потому что я использую ActiveRecord, а в базе нету таблицы search. Как можно обмануть эту систему?

Comment: Через виджет сделали? А зачем его передавать?